# Want to load only JavaScript and HTML in Firefox. Everything else should be blocked. (Save RAM and CPU Usage)

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon-sdk

I wrote a program which openes a lot of firefox-instances (up to 20). The sites are full of content and videos, pictures, cryptominers and gifs. I only want to load HTML and JavaScript to save RAM and CPU Usage. The RAM is full up to 3 - 5 GB total and CPU usage = 100%. What can i do to reduce the content of the firefox sites?

[image: List of firefox.exe processes with CPU and RAM usage]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It would be very helpful to see what you have tried so far, so nobody wastes time repeating those steps.

Comment: i tried to use firemin, searched some Addons, that did not work very well.